# My USB Policy for Intune is not working for all devices

Tags: office365, intune, intunemam

I am trying to block USB devices using Intune. It is getting blocked for some devices and for others, it's not getting blocked even when I have enrolled for all the devices. What can be the reasons that policy is not working?

[image]

I was trying to block usb for the enrolled devices it was not getting blocked using configuration policy of Intune

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? Could you be having other policies applied to the devices hence causing a policy conflict? Also, it would be worthwhile to check whether the policy was targeted correctly to the device by going to Devices > All Devices > [select one of the devices that did not apply the policy] > Device configuration. Check if the policy shows up. If not, open the policy and try assigning it to that device.  Also, you can try restarting the Intune service on the affected device as part of troubleshooting